# Let $X$ be a random variable with density $U [0, 1]$. If $X = x$, a number $Y$ is chosen between $0$ and $x$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $U [0, 1]$. If  $X = x$, a number $Y$ is chosen between $0$ and $x$.

Calculate $E (Y), V (Y), Cov (X, Y)$ and $Cov (X, X + Y)$.

I know how to calculate $E (Y)$ and $V (Y)$ but I need the density function of Y, and I don't understand how to obtain it from the hypothesis $0 \leq y \leq x \leq1$

Comment: How is Y chosen? Uniformly as well?

Comment: Notice that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,W)=E[XW]-E[X]E[W]$ for any random variables $X$ and $Y$.Thus it suffices to estimate $E[X]$, $E[Y]$, $E[X^2]$ and $E[XY]$ for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid tedious integrations, we can just notice that $(Y|X=x)\sim\text{Uniform}[0,x]$ has the same distribution as $xW$ where $W\sim\text{Uniform}[0,1].$ Thus $Y$ has the same distribution as $XW$, where $X,W$ are *independent* and each is $\text{Uniform}[0,1]$. Therefore:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[Y]&=\mathsf E[XW]=\mathsf E[X]\cdot\mathsf E[W]=etc.\\
\mathsf V[Y]&=\mathsf V[XW]=\mathsf E[\mathsf V[XW\mid X]]+\mathsf V[\mathsf E[XW\mid X]]=\mathsf E[X^2{1\over 12}]+\mathsf V[X{1\over 2}]=etc.\\
\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)&=\mathsf{Cov}(X,XW)=\mathsf E[X^2W]-\mathsf E[X]\cdot\mathsf E[XW]=etc.\\
\mathsf{Cov}(X,X+Y)&=\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)+\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf V[X]+\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=etc.
\end{align}$$

The above formulas reduce to expressions involving only the mean $(1/2)$ and variance $(1/12)$ of $\text{Uniform}[0,1]$.